# Dual nested dynamic routing in experimental app directory

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I am using `NextJS 13` and performing the following inside the `app` folder.

I am trying to use `generateStaticParams` function to achieve static generation pages on build.

This is the route: `subpage/[categoryName]/[gifId]`

So the route could be like following examples.

```
/subpage/fashion/1
/subpage/fashion/2
/subpage/fashion/3

/subpage/technology/1
/subpage/technology/2
/subpage/technology/3
/subpage/technology/4

... and so on.
```

The route `subpage/[categoryName]` won't have anything there. Might show an error or redirect some place.

The full path `subpage/[categoryName]/[gifId]` including the `[gifId]` is a must.

I need to perform REST requests to get the data for the pages.

How could I set this up inside my `page.tsx` file which will be located at: `subpage/[categoryName]/[gifId]/page.tsx` ?

If it was a single dynamic path, would be straight forward. See my implementation below for that.

But since is nested with 2 dynamic paths `[categoryName]` and `[gifId]` back to back, bit confused how to achieve this. Pls assist.

```
import MyComponent from "../../../components/MyComponent";
import { PartialGifProps, TagType} from "../../../utils/typings";
import axios from "axios";
import {apiDomain, defaultHeaders} from "../../../utils/constants";

const perPage = 40;

type Props = {
  params: {
    gifId: string,
  },
}

export const generateStaticParams = async () => {
  const url = `${apiDomain}/get_gif_count`; // I have access to modify the backend for this if it should contain category. 
  const fetchGifs = await axios.get(url, { headers: defaultHeaders });


  const { total_count: totalCount } : TagType = fetchGifs.data;

  const totalPages = Math.ceil(totalCount / perPage);

  let paramsList = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
    paramsList.push({ gifId: i.toString() })
  }

  // this paramsList would look like: 
  // [
  //   { gifId: '1', },
  //   { gifId: '2', },
  //   { gifId: '3', },
  //   .......
  // ]

  return paramsList;
}

const MyPage = async ({params: {gifId}}: Props) => {
  const url = `${apiDomain}/get_partial?page=${gifId}&per_page=${perPage}`;
  const fetchGifs = await axios.get(url, { headers: defaultHeaders });
  const { gifs } : PartialGifProps = fetchGifs.data;

  return (
    <div className='text-white'>
      <MyComponent gifs={gifs}/>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get `categoryName` in the same way you get `gifId`, through the [`params` prop](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/file-conventions/page#params-optional)

```
type Props = {
  params: {
    gifId: string,
    categoryName: string,
  },
}

const MyPage = async ({params: {gifId, categoryName}}: Props) => {
  console.log('categoryName =', categoryName);

  const url = `${apiDomain}/get_partial?page=${gifId}&per_page=${perPage}`;
  const fetchGifs = await axios.get(url, { headers: defaultHeaders });
  const { gifs } : PartialGifProps = fetchGifs.data;

  return (
    <div className='text-white'>
      <MyComponent gifs={gifs}/>
    </div>
  );
};
```